# Sqoop and hive connect to sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, hive, sqoop

I have my SQL server name and my IP but I can't manage to connect to the SQL server database to Hadoop Hive database.

I'm running the following command in coursera:

```
sqoop import 
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://myip:port;username=myusername;password=mypass;databaseName=myDB" 
--table mytablename
--hive import
```

But it says:

> "Could not load db driver class:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

Any ideas how to construct the connection string? 
Consider the servername=servername.

Comment: Do you have the SQL Server JDBC driver on the classpath?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the SQL Server driver in `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` directory?

Comment: Plz clarify, If you want to import data into Hive table or some HDFS directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Download SQL server **JDBC driver** by following command,

```
curl -L 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar.gz'| tar xz
```

Copy the JAR file to `$SQOOP_HOME/lib/` directory.

**For Java 7:**

```
cp ~/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre7/sqljdbc41.jar /$SQOOP_HOME/lib/
```

**For Java 8:**

```
cp ~/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar /$SQOOP_HOME/lib/
```